# Heroku Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku, mean

I finished implementing a mean stack up and tried deploying it on heroku. The Signup functionality of the app worked without issues on the local environment. But, once it is up on heroku, I keep getting the following error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

This is the file Heroku is complaining about

```
angular.module('app').controller('mvSignupCtrl', function($scope, mvUser, mvNotifier, $location, mvAuth){

    $scope.signup = function(){
        var newUserData = {
          username: $scope.email,
          password: $scope.password,
          firstName: $scope.fname,
          lastName: $scope.lname
        };

        mvAuth.createUser(newUserData).then(function(){

            mvNotifier.notify('User account created!');
            $location.path('/');
        }, function(reason){
            mvNotifier.error(reason);
        })
    }
});
```

All other routes work and I am able to signin and view the pages. I am not minifying anything nor using grunt or gulp. It is just a simple app. Let me know if you have any solutions.

Comment: It's unlikely that that is the correct file, since there's no '<' token in the text you pasted.

Comment: please provide the exact error from the log because the error seems a error thrown by rails, but the file is javascript, which will never show up in the heroku log because it's client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signup file was not referenced as a javascript file in a script tag. resolved now.